# Spring / Hibernate: JPA exception :: path expected for JOIN

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

Getting QuerySyntaxException trying to run this query:

```
public interface SignalRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Signal, Long> {

...
@Query("select p1 from Signal p1 LEFT JOIN Signal p2 " 
        + " ON (p1.zoneId = p2.zoneId AND p1.createdAt < p2.createdAt) "
        + " where p2.id is null AND p1.userId=?#{[0]} AND p1.pid=?#{[1]}")
```

Produces this error:

```
caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [select p1 from com.newco.models.Signal p1 LEFT JOIN Signal p2  ON (p1.zoneId = p2.zoneId AND p1.createdAt < p2.createdAt)  where p2.id is null AND p1.userId=?1 AND p1.pid=?2]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:268) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
```

This query works well when typed SQL command line (and `Ruby on Rails`) but fails with Spring/JAP.

Comment: JPQL != SQL ...

Answer (score 1):

> Path expected for join!

With JPQL, you cannot write JOIN as you do in SQL. You must precise the path of the join relation

Either you do a native SQL query :

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("YourQuery", Signal.class);
```

Either you adapt your SQL query in JPQL query.
To do it, you should change several things.

1) I am not sure JPA recognizes this syntax : `p1.userId=?#{[0]} AND p1.pid=?#{[1]}` to set parameter values. You should rather use : `p1.userId=:?1 and p1.pid=:?2`.

2)Admitting you declare in `Signal` Entity, a reflexive relation (p2), the `LEFT JOIN` condition should be something like that (`JOIN` is made on entity relation and `ON` becomes `WITH`):

```
"select p1 FROM Signal p1 LEFT JOIN p1.p2 p2 " 
        + " WITH p1.createdAt < p2.createdAt "
        + " where p2.id is null AND p1.userId=:?1 AND p1.pid=:?2
```

3)`p1.zoneId = p2.zoneId` condition should not be needed in the `WITH` if `Signal` entity has its reflexive relation based on this condition.